# Passing Base64 encodedsString in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario where I am trying to pass a base64 encoded string to a function.

My code below:

```
function imageFormatter() {
var img = '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<base64data>">';
return '<a href="#" onclick="+showImage(' + img + ')">Image</a>';
}

function showImage(image)
{
  alert(image);
}
```

Here I am trying to pass base64 image as a parameter to my function. But while executing I am getting the error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Is this the right way to pass or is there any other better way?

Comment: You should look into Typed Arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

Comment: I don't see why this code should throw an error on *execution*, but `function(image) { alert(image); }` is surely a *syntax* error (function declaration without a name). What is the error you are getting? Please provide more information and context. I can also see a problem with the argument passed to `showImage` but I don't know if you are even getting as far as calling it. *"Is this the right way to pass or is there any other better way?"* If you get an error then it cannot be the right way.

Comment: You can't alert an image. Second, does your showImage function expect an image resource like a url or base64 string or an actual <img> dom element that you appear to be passing to it?

Comment: why i am putting an alert is to make sure it returns a proper image tag .

Comment: my showimage function expects a <img> dom element..

Comment: I can see that (even though I'd say it expects an HTML string). But the code you posted cannot even be executed because it is invalid (as I mentioned in my previous comment). Please provide a more complete example and a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. Tell us which error you are getting. You don't have any benefit from letting us guess it.

Comment: Oh ok. You should use console.log(image) instead. But anyway, what is <base64data>? That looks more like a pseudocode placeholder than actual data, so that would certainly cause an error. You want that base64 data to be a JavaScript string or something right?

Comment: <base64Data> is the actual encoded String.

Comment: Best way take your Base64 string and decode online here http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html and check whether you are getting correct image or not....?

Comment: There are two more prominent problems than the Base64 string (which to the best of our knowledge is perfectly fine): The second function doesn't have a name `->` syntax error, and the JavaScript inside the `onclick` attribute will be invalid as well, since the argument is not wrapped in quotes. I.e. the value will be something like `+showImage(<img ... />)`. Alas, it looks the OP doesn't want our help, otherwise they would have already provided more information.

Comment: i am getting an error like "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "

Comment: @FelixKling i checked the base64 string its working fine.....and sorry for not putting name to js function.

Comment: So I can assume that the missing function name was not the problem? If you are making mistakes when copying the code here, then it will mask the actual problem you are having. We can only work with what you give us. And you **still** haven't told us what the error message is that you are getting. Only if you provide it we will actually be able to help you.

Comment: @FelixKling : i am getting an error like "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "

Comment: Is this the exact error message and is just "like" this error message? We need the exact error message. And when exactly is the error thrown? When you are executing `imageFormatter`? Or an other function? As I mentioned already, if you would create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo which reproduces the error, it would be much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 3):

try changing:

```
var img = '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<base64data>">';
return '<a href="#" onclick="+showImage(' + img + ')">Image</a>';
```

to

```
var img = '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<base64data>">';
return '<a href="#" onclick="showImage(\'' + img + '\')">Image</a>';
```